# gspca compilation errors / raspberry pi raspbian

Tags: gcc, raspberry-pi, kernel-module, raspbian, video4linux

I have webcam Veo Stingray

- Ox545:8333 (vendor and product ID)

I have Raspberry Pi model A
uname -r = Linux raspberrypi 4.1.15+ #830 Tue Dec 15 16:58:28 GMT 2015 armv6l GNU/Linux

gspca drivers from http://mxhaard.free.fr/spca5xx.html list this webcam as being compatible so I say 'yay'
I wget and xzf tarball
I download rpi-source
I download rpi-update

> Perform sudo rpi-update
>
> See https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-update for details on rpi-update.
>   You have to be on the latest firmware and associated kernel to be able
>   to perform the next step.
>
> Install and run rpi-source to install the source code that built the
>   latest kernel that you are running. This will create the correct entry
>   in /lib/modules for the kernel that you are running. Note: you don't
>   need to be root to run this, however the script will perform certain
>   tasks using sudo and the root password will be requested during the
>   script execution.

then I would run rpi-source and have error about compiler being different (the one I use from the one kernel was compiled with) so I make sure I use the same compiler by installing alternative

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc 4.x

then I cd into the gspcav1 folder and as root run ./gspca_build

ERROR SAYS:

```
/home/pi/gspcav1-20071224# ./gspca_build 

 REMOVE the old module if present
rmmod: ERROR: Module gspca is not currently loaded

 CLEAN gspca source tree
rm -r -f *.o decoder/.gspcadecoder.o.cmd decoder/*.o \
.gspca.o.cmd  *.o *.ko *.mod.* .[a-z]* core *.i \
*.symvers *.err

 COMPILE gspca Please Wait ....!!

 INSTALL gspca in the kernel binary tree
mkdir -p /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/usb/media/
rm -f /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/usb/media/spca5xx.ko
rm -f /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/media/video/gspca.ko
install -c -m 0644 gspca.ko /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/usb/media/
install: cannot stat ‘gspca.ko’: No such file or directory
Makefile:47: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 1

 LOAD gspca in memory 
modprobe: FATAL: Module gspca not found.

 PRINT COMPILATION MESSAGES if ERRORS look kgspca.err 
make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build SUBDIRS=/home/pi/gspcav1-20071224 CC=cc modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/root/linux-853eff4e9b369cdc20be7c538bc5a5291eeab31d'
  CC [M]  /home/pi/gspcav1-20071224/gspca_core.o
/home/pi/gspcav1-20071224/gspca_core.c:37:26: fatal error: linux/config.h: No such file or directory
 #include <linux/config.h>
                          ^
compilation terminated.
scripts/Makefile.build:258: recipe for target '/home/pi/gspcav1-20071224/gspca_core.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/pi/gspcav1-20071224/gspca_core.o] Error 1
Makefile:1384: recipe for target '_module_/home/pi/gspcav1-20071224' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/pi/gspcav1-20071224] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/linux-853eff4e9b369cdc20be7c538bc5a5291eeab31d'
Makefile:44: recipe for target 'default' failed
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

I know easy answer is get compatible logitech cam, I want hard answer obviously. Thanks!